# SonarLint sonar.issue.ignore.multicriteria does not work

Tags: intellij-idea, sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarlint-intellij

I configured our project in SonarQube to ignore the rule squid:S00103.

It works fine, but the SonarLint 2.0 for IntelliJ, configured with our server does not use this exclusion.

So i wanted to add the exclusion manually in the plugin properties, but it seems not to work.

See here:
[SonarIgnore-Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQr4p.png)